# Bash terminal on tablets

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, tablet, linux, bash

I would like to buy a tablet and use it as a netbook to work using a keyboard dock (I still like the touchscreen and stylus options over buying a netbook). I work mostly on linux machines where I need ssh, vpn and the ability to open X windows remotely. Are there terminals for the Android tablets that can do that ? Anyone with comments about Ubuntu on tablets ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, to an extent. I know there are apps that will create an SSH terminal. Most likely there are other apps that can process other types of protocols.

There are only few tablets that compatible with Ubuntu (At least work well with). The Nexus 7 and/or 10 being a prime example. From what I hear, it works very well and is almost no different from the desktop version.

In my opinion, from what you are looking for, I'd get a Nexus 7/10 and try out Android OS, and if it can't do everything you want it to, then install Ubuntu.

Comment: But do these apps create an X-window system and allow root access ?

Comment: That would require an X-Server running. Though there were some tries for that, Android does not ship with this. But you might want to take a look at the Android [XServer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=au.com.darkside.XServer) app :) See also on StackOverflow: [X-Applications over SSH in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12811124/x-applications-over-ssh-in-android)